# PHP Query response to string

Tags: php, mysql, string, email

I'm running a PHP query which returns several rows / columns. (Im returning the columns: name, quantity, unit, producer, notes) * X rows (depending on how many rows were found in the database).

```
$sql = "SELECT products.name, products.unit, lists.quantity, lists.producer, lists.notes FROM lists,products WHERE lists.familyid ='$familyid' AND lists.productid = products.id ";
$sqlmessage=mysql_query($sql);
```

Now i would like to arrange this response into a STRING, in order to email it using `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)`.

Im trying to use the following function, however im not getting the correct list but rather alot of  " fetchColumn(name) "

The Broken function:

```
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($sqlmessage); ++$i){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlmessage)){
        $name = $row->fetchColumn($i);
        $message .= "$name";
        $message .= ", ";
    }
}
```

What do i need to change to get the correct information out ? Been searching for a day now and trying different things without any success.'

Comment: how many rows supposed to be returned by the query?

Comment: It depends on which session id im checking. each session ID has  a different amount of product entries in the database.

Comment: in what format it is supposed to return the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two loops (i dont know why) and object to `mysql_fetch_array()` .Do you mean something like this?:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlmessage))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $message .= $name;
    $message .= ", ";
}
```